# How to access and store the input hidden field of a jsp page which is changing dynamically on button clicks?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

here is the script that in the jsp page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#trno=${track.track_no}" class="album-poster" data-switch="${count}" data-value="${track.track_no}">Play Button</a>

<input type="hidden" id="trnum" name="trnum" value="">
```

here is the js script that I wrote

```
$(".album-poster").on('click', function(e) {

  var dataSwitchId = $(this).attr('data-switch');
  var datavalue = $(this).attr('data-value');

  //Add value to hidden field.
  $('#trnum').val(datavalue);
  
  //Show hidden field value
  console.log($('#trnum').val())

  ap.list.switch(dataSwitchId);

  ap.play();

  $("#aplayer").addClass('showPlayer');
});
```

here the anchor tag is in the foreach loop such that of different values will be there in the data-value attribute in the anchor tag

here I want to store these data values to the database such that when I'm trying to access like

```
$(".album-poster").on('click', function(e) {

  var dataSwitchId = $(this).attr('data-switch');
  var datavalue = $(this).attr('data-value');

  //Add value to hidden field.
  $('#trnum').val(datavalue);
  
  //Show hidden field value
  console.log($('#trnum').val())
  ****<%System.out.println(request.getParameter("trnum"));%>****

  ap.list.switch(dataSwitchId);

  ap.play();

  $("#aplayer").addClass('showPlayer');
});
```

in the highlighted code that I'm printing in the console it is printing null I need these values which are clicked to store them into the database and how can I get access them and store into the java list.

how can I do it ?

Comment: without submiting `form` or using `ajax` you cannot access `request` here ? And why you have mix `js` and `jsp` ?

Comment: @ Swati   I'm a beginner don't mind , I need to access those without submitting the form is it possible ?

Comment: No you cannot access them like that.

Comment: On every click data should go to backened ? if yes use ajax grabbed that value and simply send it to server and if you want to collect all value first then you can store them in array at front-end and then send  that to server using ajax .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219126/discussion-between-swati-and-sri-harsha-damarla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit your data to server to access `request` object .One way to achieve this is using ajax .You can send the `datavalue` which is clicked by user to backend and save it .So your **jquery** code will look like below :

```
 $(".album-poster").on('click', function(e) {
    
      var dataSwitchId = $(this).attr('data-switch');
      var datavalue = $(this).attr('data-value');
 //chcking if datavalue is not null
      if (datavalue != null) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "your_backend_url", //url or servlet
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            trnum: datavalue
          }, //pass data to backend access same using request.getParameter("trnum") in doGet method servlet
          success: function(data) {
            console.log("done");//this will print on success in browser console
          }
        });
    
      }
      ap.list.switch(dataSwitchId);
    
      ap.play();
    
      $("#aplayer").addClass('showPlayer');
    });
```

At backend get that data which is passed by user using `request.getParameter("trnum")` and do further operations .